# Laravel 7 Unable to delete, redirected to home instead of controller redirect

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have an authenticated user called vendor which I can add, update businesses. However, when I try to delete an entry, it redirects to the home page instead of the redirect I specified in the controller. I am not sure if it has something to do with the way I have my middle ware set up but in the end, it gives me the message I have for a failed auth in the middleware which is "You are not permitted to access the admin dashboard". I am sure I am doing something wrong either in the middle ware or in the controller. I should mention that for the super admin, this middle ware is working fine. That is to say, the admin who can block and unblock users and see all the businesses entered. Here is the following code.

vendorMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class VendorMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'vendor') {
            if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isBanned) {
                $banned = Auth::user()->isBanned == "1";
                Auth::logout();

                if ($banned == 1) {
                    $message = 'Your account has been Banned. Please contact the administrator.';
                }
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', $message)->withErrors(['email' => 'Your account has been Banned. Please contact the administrator.']);
            }
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

The destroy function in my resource vendorEmpresaController.php

```
 /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {

        $empresa = Empresa::find($id);
        if ($empresa != null) {
            $empresa->delete();
            return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
            // return redirect()->to('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
        }
        return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'ID Equivocado! La empresa no fue borrado.');
    }
```

My index.blade.php where the form and modals reside

```
@extends('layouts.vendor-admin')


@section('content')
<!-- Start delete modal-->

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Borrar</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

    <form action="vendor-empresas/{vendor_empresa}" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle mb-4" style="color: #ffc107; font-size: 32px;"></i>
        </div>
            <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase">¿Estás Seguro/a?
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sí, Borralo!</button>

      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--end delete modal-->

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="card mb-4 wow fadeIn">

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body d-sm-flex justify-content-between">

        <h4 class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 pt-1">
          <a href="/">Inicio</a>
          <span>/</span>
          <span>Empresas Registradas</span>
        </h4>
        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success fade-message" role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Añadir Empresa</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="/vendor-empresas" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="erfc" id="orangeForm-erfc" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-erfc">RFC</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="enombre" id="orangeForm-enombre" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-enombre">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecalle" id="orangeForm-ecalle" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecalle">Calle</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecolonia" id="orangeForm-ecolonia" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecolonia">Colonia</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eciudad" id="orangeForm-eciudad" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eciudad">Ciudad</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eestado" id="orangeForm-eestado" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eestado">Estado</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecpostal" id="orangeForm-ecpostal" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecpostal">Codigo Postal</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="epais" id="orangeForm-epais" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-epais">País</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="user_id" readonly id="orangeForm-euser" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                            <input type="text" name="eregby" readonly id="orangeForm-eregby" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Añadir</button>
                </div>
            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Añadir</a>
</div>


      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Heading -->

    <!--Grid row-->
      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="row">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card">
            <!-- List group links -->
             <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="datatable2" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
                           <th>RFC</th>
                           <th>Nombre</th>
                           <th>Calle</th>
                           <th>Colonia</th>
                           <th>Ciudad</th>
                           <th>Estado</th>
                           <th>Codigo Postal</th>
                           <th>País</th>
                           <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                         <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $empresa->id }}">
                        <td style="display: none;">{{ $empresa->id }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->erfc }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->enombre }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecalle }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecolonia }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eciudad }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eestado }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecpostal }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->epais }}</td>

                         <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                            <a class="badge badge-pill btn-primary px-3 py-2" href="{{ url('vendor-empresas/'.$empresa->id).'/edit' }}">Editar</a>
                            <a class="delete badge badge-pill btn-danger px-3 py-2">Borrar</a>
                        </div>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>


            </div>
            <!-- List group links -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->
      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->
  </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let table = $('#datatable2').DataTable();
 // Start Delete Record
 table.on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
            $tr = $tr.prev('.parent')
        }
        let data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#deleteForm').attr('action', '/delete-empresa/'+data[0]);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    });
    // End Delete Record
});
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.fade-message').slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

and finally the image of my route:list
[image: Route List]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

**Edit**: I have tried with EmpresaPolicy.php and didn't have any luck either with or without the @can. I had @can('delete', $empresa) @endcan but it said that the variable $empresa was undefined. So, in EmpresaPolicy.php, I have:

```
public function delete(User $user, Empresa $empresa)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

In my AuthServiceProvider, I have:

```
    protected $policies = [
            'App\Empresa' => 'App\Policies\EmpresaPolicy',
        ];
I tried this in my vendorEmpresasController.php 
public function destroy($id)
    {

        $empresa = Empresa::find($id);
        $this->authorizeResource(Empresa::class, 'delete', $empresa);
        if ($empresa != null) {
            $empresa->delete();
            return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
            // return redirect()->to('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
        } else {
            return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'ID Equivocado! La empresa no fue borrado.');
        }
    }
```

And, finally, in my web.php, I have:

```
Route::delete('/vendor-empresas/{vendor_empresa}', 'vendorEmpresaController@destroy');
```

I am still getting redirected back to home when I want to be redirected to /vendor-empresas
Any help appreciated. Thank you.
**Edit #2**
Here is the dd output of vendormiddleware.php
[image: Dump and Die results]

On clicking the delete confirmation:
[image: Denied]

Comment: So basically `Auth::user()->role_as == 'vendor'` fails to be truthy?

Comment: Could you expand your question with a user from the database, the one which is working and the one which isn't?

Comment: Remove `else { return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard'); }` in **vendorMiddleware**

Comment: Hello Sobir and RCRalph. I am not sure if the role_as == vendor comes back truthy or falsey but, after deleting the line suggested by Sobir in the middleware, I was still getting the same message and found I had something similar in Adin middleware:
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not permitted to access the dashboard Fool!');
        }
    }}
Any clues? Thank you.
edit-works delete-fails

Comment: If I remove the else statements in both middleware, I get:
Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is: `if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'vendor')`

If condition returns `false` you will receive this: `return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard');`

Conclusion is: If you are redirected to `/home` and you see `'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard'` message, it means that currently logged user field `role_as` is not equal to `'vendor'`.

Comment: Indeed strange as in the db, role_as == vendor. Thus I am able to view, create and update, just not delete.

Comment: Did you check user object in middleware? I mean - in middleware, before first if do this: `dd(Auth::user());`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Pjplonka. I have edited my post to show the details of the dd(Auth::user());

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles ok, do you use that message: `'You are not permitted to access the vendor dashboard'` in your application except that VendorMiddleware?

Comment: The adminMiddleware warning says, you are not permitted to access the Admin Dashboard and the VendorMiddleware says, you are not permintted to access the Vendor dashboard (if it is just a standard user).

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles can you show result of `dd(Auth::check())` at the first line in `handle` method? (in VendorMiddleware)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220447/discussion-between-erik-james-robles-and-pjplonka).

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem. Number One, in my web.php file, I needed to keep my vendor and admin groups and their perspective routes isolated. Here is what it looks like now:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('frontend.index');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isUser']], function () {

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });

    // Usuarios
    Route::get('registered-user', 'Admin\RegisteredController@index');
    Route::delete('/user-delete/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@destroy');
    Route::get('role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@edit');
    Route::put('role-update/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@updaterole');
    // Empresas
    Route::get('registered-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@index');
    Route::post('save-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@store');
    Route::get('/edit-empresa/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@edit');
    Route::put('/empresa-update/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@update');
    Route::delete('/delete-empresa/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@destroy');
    // Empleados
    Route::get('registered-empleado', 'Admin\EmpleadoController@index');
    Route::get('/edit-empleado/{id}', 'Admin\EmpleadoController@edit');
    Route::put('/empleado-update/{id}', 'Admin\EmpleadoController@update');
    Route::post('save-empleado', 'Admin\EmpleadoController@store');
    Route::delete('/delete-empleado/{id}', 'Admin\EmpleadoController@destroy');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVendor']], function () {
    Route::get('/vendor-dashboard', function () {
        return view('vendor.dashboard');
    });
    
    Route::resource('vendor-empresas', 'vendorEmpresaController');
Route::resource('vendor-empleados', 'vendorEmpleadoController');

Route::delete('/vendor-empresas/{vendor_empresa}', 'vendorEmpresaController@destroy');
    
});
```

2nd: In my index for the vendor, I was calling the admins delete function and not the vendor delete function that is in VendorEmpresaController. Here is the code now:

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let table = $('#datatable2').DataTable();
 // Start Delete Record
 table.on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
            $tr = $tr.prev('.parent')
        }
        let data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#deleteForm').attr('action', '/vendor-empresas/'+data[0]);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    });
    // End Delete Record
});
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.fade-message').slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

And here is the code for the Controller in vendorEmpressaController located in the Vendor Folder:

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {

        $empresa = Empresa::find($id);
        if ($empresa != null) {

            $empresa->delete();
            return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
            // return redirect()->to('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'Empresa Borrado Exitosamente.');
        } else {
            return redirect('/vendor-empresas')->with('status', 'ID Equivocado! La empresa no fue borrado.');
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone with the same issue. Cheers.